# Error message in Monogame: Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: SDL2.dll

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, monogame

I'm trying to run a project built in Visual studio under Monogame. It builds successfully, but when I run it I get the following error message:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: SDL2.dll
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) SDL2.SDL:SDL_SetMainReady ()
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.SDL2_GameWindow..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.SDL2_GamePlatform..ctor (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamePlatform.Create (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MovingTeddyBears.Game1..ctor () [0x00000] in /home/stefan/Downloads/LinuxMonoGameMovingTeddyBears/Game1.cs:30 
  at MovingTeddyBears.Program.Main () [0x00001] in /home/stefan/Downloads/LinuxMonoGameMovingTeddyBears/Program.cs:19 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: SDL2.dll
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) SDL2.SDL:SDL_SetMainReady ()
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.SDL2_GameWindow..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.SDL2_GamePlatform..ctor (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamePlatform.Create (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) 

[0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MovingTeddyBears.Game1..ctor () [0x00000] in /home/stefan/Downloads/LinuxMonoGameMovingTeddyBears/Game1.cs:30 
  at MovingTeddyBears.Program.Main () [0x00001] in /home/stefan/Downloads/LinuxMonoGameMovingTeddyBears/Program.cs:19 
The application was terminated by a signal: SIGHUP
```

Here is the actual code:

Game1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace MovingTeddyBears
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
        const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;

        // teddy bears
        TeddyBear bear0;
        TeddyBear bear1;
        TeddyBear bear2;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

            // set resolution to 800 by 600
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = WINDOW_WIDTH;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = WINDOW_HEIGHT;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            // create teddy bears
            bear0 = new TeddyBear(Content, "teddybear0", 100, 100, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
            bear1 = new TeddyBear(Content, "teddybear1", 200, 100, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
            bear2 = new TeddyBear(Content, "teddybear2", 300, 100, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            // update teddy bears
            bear0.Update();
            bear1.Update();
            bear2.Update();

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            // draw teddy bears
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            bear0.Draw(spriteBatch);
            bear1.Draw(spriteBatch);
            bear2.Draw(spriteBatch);
            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
#region Using Statements
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
#endregion

namespace MovingTeddyBears
{
    static class Program
    {
        private static Game1 game;

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            game = new Game1();
            game.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

TeddyBear.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace MovingTeddyBears
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A class for a teddy bear
    /// </summary>
    class TeddyBear
    {
        #region Fields

        // drawing support
        Texture2D sprite;
        Rectangle drawRectangle;

        // velocity information
        Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);

        // bouncing support
        int windowWidth;
        int windowHeight;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        ///  Constructs a teddy bear with random direction and speed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="contentManager">the content manager for loading content</param>
        /// <param name="spriteName">the name of the sprite for the teddy bear</param>
        /// <param name="x">the x location of the center of the teddy bear</param>
        /// <param name="y">the y location of the center of the teddy bear</param>
        /// <param name="windowWidth">the window width</param>
        /// <param name="windowHeight">the window height</param>
        public TeddyBear(ContentManager contentManager, string spriteName, int x, int y,
            int windowWidth, int windowHeight)
        {
            this.windowWidth = windowWidth;
            this.windowHeight = windowHeight;

            LoadContent(contentManager,spriteName, x, y);

            // generate random velocity
            Random rand = new Random();
            int speed = rand.Next(5) + 3;
            double angle = 2 * Math.PI * rand.NextDouble();
            velocity.X = (float)Math.Cos(angle) * speed;
            velocity.Y = -1 * (float)Math.Sin(angle) * speed;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs a teddy bear with the given characteristics
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="contentManager">the content manager for loading content</param>
        /// <param name="spriteName">the name of the sprite for the teddy bear</param>
        /// <param name="x">the x location of the center of the teddy bear</param>
        /// <param name="y">the y location of the center of the teddy bear</param>
        /// <param name="velocity">the velocity vector for the teddy bear</param>
        /// <param name="windowWidth">the window width</param>
        /// <param name="windowHeight">the window height</param>
        public TeddyBear(ContentManager contentManager, string spriteName, int x, int y,
            Vector2 velocity, int windowWidth, int windowHeight)
        {
            this.windowWidth = windowWidth;
            this.windowHeight = windowHeight;

            LoadContent(contentManager, spriteName, x, y);
            this.velocity = velocity;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Updates the teddy bear's location, bouncing if necessary
        /// </summary>
        public void Update()
        {
            // move the teddy bear
            drawRectangle.X += (int)(velocity.X);
            drawRectangle.Y += (int)(velocity.Y);

            // bounce as necessary
            BounceTopBottom();
            BounceLeftRight();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Draws the teddy bear
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="spriteBatch">the sprite batch to use</param>
        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(sprite, drawRectangle, Color.White);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Loads the content for the teddy bear
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="contentManager">the content manager to use</param>
        /// <param name="spriteName">the name of the sprite for the teddy bear</param>
        /// <param name="x">the x location of the center of the teddy bear</param>
        /// <param name="y">the y location of the center of the teddy bear</param>
        private void LoadContent(ContentManager contentManager, string spriteName, 
            int x, int y)
        {
            // load content and set remainder of draw rectangle
            sprite = contentManager.Load<Texture2D>(spriteName);
            drawRectangle = new Rectangle(x - sprite.Width / 2, 
                y - sprite.Height / 2, sprite.Width,
                sprite.Height);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Bounces the teddy bear off the top and bottom window borders if necessary
        /// </summary>
        private void BounceTopBottom()
        {
            if (drawRectangle.Y < 0)
            {
                // bounce off top
                drawRectangle.Y = 0;
                velocity.Y *= -1;
            }
            else if ((drawRectangle.Y + drawRectangle.Height) > windowHeight)
            {
                // bounce off bottom
                drawRectangle.Y = windowHeight - drawRectangle.Height;
                velocity.Y *= -1;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Bounces the teddy bear off the left and right window borders if necessary
        /// </summary>
        private void BounceLeftRight()
        {
            if (drawRectangle.X < 0)
            {
                // bounc off left
                drawRectangle.X = 0;
                velocity.X *= -1;
            }
            else if ((drawRectangle.X + drawRectangle.Width) > windowWidth)
            {
                // bounce off right
                drawRectangle.X = windowWidth - drawRectangle.Width;
                velocity.X *= -1;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

I found this page http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/dllnotfoundexception/ but that didn't solve the problem. Actually, when I run `ldconfig -p |grep libgdiplus`
I get

```
libgdiplus.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so.0
libgdiplus.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so
```

so the .so file(s) don't seem to be the problem (I think, not sure though).

Comment: possible duplicate of [MonoGame application says SDL.dll is missing, even though it's there. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171606/monogame-application-says-sdl-dll-is-missing-even-though-its-there-why)

Comment: David, I don't think it's a duplicate - the error messages in the two questions are different. Please see the answer below for details (they're too long to post in a comment and I still haven't solved the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's a duplicate because if you look closely at the error messages, they're different. The Tao.Sdl.dll.config file is present in the /bin/Debug folder. As suggested in http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/dllnotfoundexception/ I typed 
 `MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug mono /home/stefan/Downloads/LinuxMonoGameMovingTeddyBears/bin/Debug/MovingTeddyBears.exe`

and I got

```
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Image addref mscorlib[0x1620550] -> /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll[0x161fad0]: 2
Mono: AOT module '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll.so' not found: /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/mscorlib/mscorlib.config'.
Mono: GC_MAJOR: (mature allocation failure) pause 0.58ms, total 0.58ms, bridge 0.00ms major 384K/128K los 0K/0K
Mono: Assembly mscorlib[0x1620550] added to domain MovingTeddyBears.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/home/stefan/.mono/config'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/home/stefan/Downloads/LinuxMonoGameMovingTeddyBears/bin/Debug/MovingTeddyBears.exe'.
Mono: Image addref MovingTeddyBears[0x1689590] -> /home/stefan/Downloads/LinuxMonoGameMovingTeddyBears/bin/Debug/MovingTeddyBears.exe[0x161e6c0]: 3
Mono: Assembly MovingTeddyBears[0x1689590] added to domain MovingTeddyBears.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT module '/home/stefan/Downloads/LinuxMonoGameMovingTeddyBears/bin/Debug/MovingTeddyBears.exe.so' not found: /home/stefan/Downloads/LinuxMonoGameMovingTeddyBears/bin/Debug/MovingTeddyBears.exe.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/home/stefan/Downloads/LinuxMonoGameMovingTeddyBears/bin/Debug/MovingTeddyBears.exe'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/home/stefan/Downloads/LinuxMonoGameMovingTeddyBears/bin/Debug/MovingTeddyBears.exe.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/MovingTeddyBears/MovingTeddyBears.config'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/home/stefan/Downloads/LinuxMonoGameMovingTeddyBears/bin/Debug/MovingTeddyBears.exe'.
Mono: AOT module '/home/stefan/Downloads/LinuxMonoGameMovingTeddyBears/bin/Debug/MovingTeddyBears.exe.so' not found: /home/stefan/Downloads/LinuxMonoGameMovingTeddyBears/bin/Debug/MovingTeddyBears.exe.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Ref addref MovingTeddyBears[0x1689590] -> mscorlib[0x1620550]: 2
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/home/stefan/Downloads/LinuxMonoGameMovingTeddyBears/bin/Debug/MonoGame.Framework.dll'.
Mono: Image addref MonoGame.Framework[0x168e8f0] -> /home/stefan/Downloads/LinuxMonoGameMovingTeddyBears/bin/Debug/MonoGame.Framework.dll[0x168da10]: 2
Mono: Assembly MonoGame.Framework[0x168e8f0] added to domain MovingTeddyBears.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT module '/home/stefan/Downloads/LinuxMonoGameMovingTeddyBears/bin/Debug/MonoGame.Framework.dll.so' not found: /home/stefan/Downloads/LinuxMonoGameMovingTeddyBears/bin/Debug/MonoGame.Framework.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/home/stefan/Downloads/LinuxMonoGameMovingTeddyBears/bin/Debug/MonoGame.Framework.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/home/stefan/Downloads/LinuxMonoGameMovingTeddyBears/bin/Debug/MonoGame.Framework.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/MonoGame.Framework/MonoGame.Framework.config'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref MovingTeddyBears[0x1689590] -> MonoGame.Framework[0x168e8f0]: 2
Mono: Assembly Ref addref MonoGame.Framework[0x168e8f0] -> mscorlib[0x1620550]: 3
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/home/stefan/Downloads/LinuxMonoGameMovingTeddyBears/bin/Debug/MovingTeddyBears.exe.config'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll'.
Mono: Image addref System[0x169ea60] -> /usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll[0x169db20]: 2
Mono: Assembly System[0x169ea60] added to domain MovingTeddyBears.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT module '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll.so' not found: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Actually, there's a lot more, but it's too long to post here. Also, as suggested in http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/dllnotfoundexception/ I had a look at the /usr/local/lib/libgdiplus.so file, which turns out to be a link to libgdiplus.so.0.0.0, but when I try to open it with gedit or vi everything is scrambled, i.e. all I see are question marks and weird characters. Can somebody help me?